# I keep getting unexpected token `/bin/busybox.exe' error in sed. How can I resolve this?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, syntax, busybox

I can modify the header and trailer of a single file that looks like:

```
header1=randomstring,header2=0000
body body body
header1=randomerstring,header2=00000
```

with this command:

`sed "s/header1=.*header2=/header1=teststring1.teststring2.$(date +%d%m%Y)teststring3,header2=/" file`

to get:

```
header1=teststring1.teststring2051919teststring3,header2=0000
body body body
header1=teststring1.teststring2051919teststring3,header2=00000
```

When I try to use a for loop (see below) to apply the above command to multiple files with the same prefix, I keep getting this error:`` bash: syntax error near unexpected token `/bin/busybox.exe' ``. How can I fix this? Also the command for the single file, prints out the file contents, I would like to remove this when I iterate through the files, I am just not certain what to remove.

The below is the for loop command that produces the error:

`for file in fileprefix.*; sed "s/header1=.*header2=/header1=teststring1.teststring2.$(date +%d%m%Y)teststring3,header2=/" i; done`

Again, the error is  `` bash: syntax error near unexpected token `/bin/busybox.exe'. ``

Comment: You're missing a `do`.

Comment: Copy/paste your code into http://shellcheck.net and fix the error messages it reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `do` in front of 'sed' in the loop and it should work; do and done come in pairs only.

Comment: Wow I was looking at this for too long -_- Thanks!